# Substitution CAST for MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to report out my query, but 'CAST' is not allowed in Access. I've updated my parentheses as instructed, but still coming up with a 'Syntax error in JOIN operation." Any suggestions as to how I should properly set my parentheses?

```
select v.VendorID, v.Name,
CCur(Format(sum(p.ListPrice * (1 - sp.DiscountPercent) * od.OrderQuantity), "0.00")) as Sales,
sum(p.ListPrice-p.Cost) as Profit,
sum(od.OrderQuantity) as Quantitiy, sum(sp.DiscountPercent) as Discounts
from ((((vendor v
join product p
on v.VendorID = p.VendorID)
join OrderDetail od
on p.ProductID = od.ProductID)
join OrderHeader oh
on od.OrderID = oh.OrderID)
join SalesPromotion sp
on od.SalesPromotionID = sp.SalesPromotionID)
where year(oh.OrderDate) = 2014
Group by v.VendorID, v.Name
order by Sales DESC
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is here rounding to two decimals.

As you are handling amounts, you should convert to *Currency*, thus:

```
CCur(Format(sum(p.ListPrice * (1 - sp.DiscountPercent) * od.OrderQuantity), "0.00")) as Sales,
```

Comment: Access SQL expects parenthesis around the Join-On statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use type conversion function from MS-Access.

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Type-Conversion-Functions-8ebb0e94-2d43-4975-bb13-87ac8d1a2202

Maybe CDbl will help you in this scenario.